# Un-breaking an analyzed field in kibana

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have an ELK stack that receives from filebeat structured JSON logs like these:

```
{"what": "Connected to proxy service", "who": "proxy.service", "when": "03.02.2016 13:29:51", "severity": "DEBUG", "more": {"host": "127.0.0.1", "port": 2004}}
{"what": "Service registered with discovery", "who": "proxy.discovery", "when": "03.02.2016 13:29:51", "severity": "DEBUG", "more": {"ctx": {"node": "igz0", "ip": "127.0.0.1:5301", "irn": "proxy"}, "irn": "igz0.proxy.827378e7-3b67-49ef-853c-242de033e645"}}
{"what": "Exception raised while setting service value", "who": "proxy.discovery", "when": "03.02.2016 13:46:34", "severity": "WARNING", "more": {"exc": "ConnectionRefusedError('Connection refused',)", "service": "igz0.proxy.827378e7-3b67-49ef-853c-242de033e645"}}
```

The "more" field which is a nested JSON is broken down (not sure by what part of the stack) to different fields ("more.host", "more.ctx" and such) in kibana.

This is my beats input:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter {
  if [type] == "node" {
    json {
      source => "message"
      add_field => {
        "who" => "%{name}"
        "what" => "%{msg}"
        "severity" => "%{level}"
        "when" => "%{time}"
      }
    }
  } else {
    json {
      source => "message"
    }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "when" , "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"]
  }
}
```

And this is my output:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost"]
    sniffing => true
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Is there any way of making a field which will contain the entire "more" field without breaking it apart?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a ruby filter to take the hash and convert it back into a string.

```
filter {
   ruby {
      code => "event['more'] = event['more'].to_s"
   }
}
```

You'd probably want to surround it with an `if` to make sure that the field exists first.

Comment: Where should I add this filter?

Comment: Somewhere between your `input{}` and `output{}`... Hard to say without seeing your config file.